# Sending SignalR message to the specific user problem. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: c#, angular, signalr, asp.net-core-2.2

First of all, when I am sending SignalR message to all clients, everything **works fine**, with:

```
public async Task SendMessage(GameStateModel game)
{
    UpdateExistingGame(game);

    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", game); //todo: send only to users in current game
}
```

and in my client:

```
public addGameStateListener = (): void => {
  this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message: GameState) => {
    if (message.gameId == this.game.gameState.gameId) {
      this.game.setGame(message);
    }
  });
};
```

**Now, when I am trying to send it to the specific client**, I am doing something like this:

```
public async Task SendMessage(GameStateModel game) //todo: SendMessageAndUpdateCachedGame(GameStateModel game)
{
    UpdateExistingGame(game);

    await SendToUsersInGame(game);
}

private async Task SendToUsersInGame(GameStateModel game)
{
    foreach (string user in game.PlayersNames)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            string id = await GetUserId(user);
            await Clients.User(id).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", game);
        }
    }
}

private async Task<string> GetUserId(string user) //from auth DB
{
    return await _userService.GetUserId(user);
}
```

where client-side code is still the same:

```
public addGameStateListener = (): void => {
  this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message: GameState) => {
    if (message.gameId == this.game.gameState.gameId) {
      this.game.setGame(message);
    }
  });
};
```

**NOTE** please note, that `GetUserId` is retreiving user ID from the database, but it is the same as `Context.User.Identity.Name`.

And I am not getting any notification at the client. The problem is, that in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#IUserIdProvider) it is written, that in hub it supposed to be:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string userId, string message)
    {
        Clients.User(userId).send(message);
    }
}
```

and it is very confusing, becaue there is no such method as a `Send(string message)`. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** Based [on this GitHub answer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17106#issuecomment-554080681), when sending the individual message I tried:

```
foreach (string user in game.PlayersNames)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
    {
        string id = await GetUserId(user);
        await Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", game);
    }
}
```

So now the question is, how to get every user's individual `Context.ConnectionId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I solved the problem. As per question update, `Context.ConnectionId` is different than `Context.User.Identity.Name`, and you can make individual message calls only using `Context.ConnectionId`.

So I created cached `Dictionary<string, string>` holding user name and connection id:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> GetUserConnectionIdList()
{
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.ConnectionIdList, out Dictionary<string, string> result))
    {
        result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _cache.Set(CacheKeys.ConnectionIdList, result);
    }

    return result;
}

public void SetConnectionIdList(Dictionary<string, string> list)
{
    _cache.Set(CacheKeys.ConnectionIdList, list);
}

public static class CacheKeys
{
    public static string ConnectionIdList { get { return "_ConnectionIdList"; } }
}
```

Next, in my hub class, `OnConnectedAsync` I am adding new user to the dictionary, and `OnDisconnectedAsync` I remove user from dictionary:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    string userName = await GetUserName(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    Dictionary<string, string> ids = _memoryAccess.GetUserConnectionIdList();
    ids.Add(userName, connectionId);

    _memoryAccess.SetConnectionIdList(ids);
}

public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception ex)
{
    string userName = await GetUserName(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string userDisplay = await GetUserDisplay(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    Dictionary<string, string> ids = _memoryAccess.GetUserConnectionIdList();
    ids.Remove(userName);
    _memoryAccess.SetConnectionIdList(ids);
}
```

And that is it. Now I can make individual calls:

```
public async Task SendMessage(GameStateModel game)
{
    UpdateExistingGame(game);

    await SendToUsersInGame(game);
}

private async Task SendToUsersInGame(GameStateModel game)
{
    foreach (string user in game.PlayersNames)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            string id = GetConnectionId(user);
            await Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", game);
        }
    }
}

private string GetConnectionId(string user)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> ids = _memoryAccess.GetUserConnectionIdList();
    return ids[user];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I tried to solve the same problem, so my client has his id(the same in db and client side), I added if statement like if(this.client.id == received.id) => do smth. It works correctly.

Comment: Where should I place `if(this.client.id == received.id) => do smth`? In hub or client side code? Where do you take `received.id` from? And where `this.client.id` from?

Comment: @bakunet try to change this like: 
 private async Task SendToUsersInGame(GameStateModel game)
        {
            foreach (string user in game.PlayersNames)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
                {
                    string id = await GetUserId(user);
                    await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", game);
                }
            }
        }
and then check on client, if it has id, which was recived
if (message.gameId == this.game.gameState.gameId) {
        this.game.setGame(message);

Comment: @bakunet I don't this it's optimal decision, but if you just need a working solution, try it